# Recommendations on gate driver circuit to pass +/-230V AC?

Tags: ac, solid-state-relay

I am looking for recommendations on how i would implement a circuit to drive a mosfet that will pass  230V+/-  AC. I was thinking of using a gate drive transformer but i am unsure on how to approach this since the source of the FET is not a DC voltage but the +/-230V. It's a relay with a MOSFET plus the gate drive circuit. Any and all ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: As single MOSFET cannot switch 230 VAC, you need back to back MOSFETs.

Comment: If it is AC with substantial current you will need both P-channel and N-channel MOSFET modules driven by a PWM supply, acting as a isolated switch. Or you can use a bridge rectifier and a N-channel MOSFET, with a PWM isolated switch

Comment: Is this a switch or a PWM or phase control?  If it's an on/off switch you can't use a  simple gate drive transformer as you can't keep the FET on with 100% duty cycle.  You could look at the optically coupled photovoltaic gate drivers if you don't need super fast switching?

Comment: You want to use a set of SCRs or a TRIAC and drive them from a opto-triac. Search STmicro for datasheets and application based on expected load